# Can't login to chat.meta

Tags: support, chat, login

I can't login to chat.meta.stackexchange.com. When I click the login link from inside a chatroom, the page reloads and I seem to be redirected right back to the room, without being logged in. Same when I click the login link from the topbar.

I've tried clearing all my cookies matching `stack`. This quite effectively logged me out of everything else, but it didn't help my situation on chat.mse. I also tried a [global logout](https://stackexchange.com/users/logout/global), to no effect. I can log in successfully from an incognito window.

Any ideas?

Chrome 40.0.2214.115 on OS X 10.10.

Comment: Do you happen to be using HTTP Everywhere? I've had this happen in the past, which required me to temporarily disable it.

Comment: @KevinBrown Maaaaaaaybe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As expected, this was caused by me being an idiot. I decided that it would be a wonderful idea to start using HTTPS Everywhere again, 'cause security. Turns out it's so secure it locks me out of chat. Which I guess would help me not click insecure links.

Bad script.

Comment: *spams tv-tropes links in chat*

Comment: Feature request: have that plugin indicate when it's messing with the page, e.g. flashing key icon in the title bar.